# Accessibility service not listed in services?

Tags: android, service, accessibility, accessibilityservice

Well I'm trying to implement one of this services, I'm using the code from here: http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#create but I can't enable the service since I don't see it in system settings. Could anyone help me out?

Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MyAccessibilityService.java

```
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService
{
public static final String TAG = "volumeMaster";

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "***** onAccessibilityEvent");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got event from: " + event.getPackageName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt()
{
    Log.v(TAG, "***** onInterrupt");
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected()
{
    Log.v(TAG, "***** onServiceConnected");

    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    setServiceInfo(info);

}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I left some important things in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, so now its working perfectly. Here's the new manifest

```
    <service
        android:name=".NotificationService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        class=".NotificationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name=".NotificationService"
                android:value=".NotificationService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
```

Comment: `class=".NotificationService"` its the class of it

Comment: can u pls update your post by adding NotificationService class implmentation i m using code but not getting response on recieving notification from whats app

Comment: Its the same as the one posted as `MyAccessibilityService` I just changed the name.

Answer (score 4):

It took me 2hrs to realize that I had a typo in the `<accessibility-service />` tag in my `.xml` file.

I had written `<accessability-service />` instead of `<accessibility-service />`.

If you are like me, you're welcome(and copy-past *everything*).

Comment: You are absolute legend. I faced the same typo

Comment: Been stuck with this problem for 3 days, looking through merged manifests and diving into the libraries like a maniac, just for missing the second s. Check your spelling guys.